# Issue in creating custom models using Apache OpenNLP. No output while testing model

Tags: model, opennlp

I am facing an issue while trying to create custom model. The issue is I created a custom model based on a training file and the training is successful.
However, when I test the model with a sample input(infact took it from the training file itself), this does not give any output.
I even tried with more than 15000 sentences but it never gives me an output.
1. Code tried :-

```
    package com.tcs.ai.opennlp.anothercustommodel.anothercustommodel;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Collections;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameSample;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameSampleDataStream;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;
public class AnotherCustomModel {
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        InputStream is=null;
        String trainingDataFile = "en-ner-person.train";
        String outputModelFile = "en-ner-person.bin";
        String sentence[] = {"Sunil", "61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29" };
        train(trainingDataFile, outputModelFile, "person");
        try {
            predict(sentence, outputModelFile);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Errror Preditct" + e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
    private static void train(String trainingDataFile, String outputModelFile, String tagToFind) {
        NameSampleDataStream nss = null;
        try {
            nss = new NameSampleDataStream(new PlainTextByLineStream(new java.io.FileReader(trainingDataFile)));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        TokenNameFinderModel model = null;
        try {
            model = NameFinderME.train("en", tagToFind, nss, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
        } catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
            File outFile = new File(outputModelFile);
            FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            model.serialize(outFileStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
    private  static void predict(String sentence[], String modelFile) throws Exception {
        InputStream is1 ;
        is1 = new FileInputStream("en-ner-person.bin");
        TokenNameFinderModel model1 = new TokenNameFinderModel(is1);
        String sd;
        NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model1); 
      StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        Span[] sp = nameFinder.find(sentence);
        nameFinder.clearAdaptiveData();
        for (Span span : sp) {
          for (int i=span.getStart(); i<span.getEnd(); i++) {
            fd.append(sentence[i] + "\n");
          }
        }
        sd = fd.toString();        
        System.out.println("Name Detected:[" + sd + "]");
    }
}
```

2. en-ner-person.train :-

   ```
   <START:person> Sunil <END> , 61 years old , will join the board as a
   ```

   nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .

I even tried with more than 15000 sentences. Unfortunately, there is no error and there is no output also when I test my model(model creation was also successful

Comment: are you sure your catch block in the train method is not getting hit? It's empty so just asking.

Comment: yes. can you please share a working sample of a)Training model b)Training file c)Testing model. That will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are giving your input as :
`String sentence[] = {"Sunil", "61 years old , will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29" };`

which is unnecessary. As an OpenNLP model is trained using [maxent modeling](http://maxent.sourceforge.net/howto.html).

you should try giving a sentence or just a text file and let the opennlp use it model on that bag of words to extract the entity.

Hope this helps.

**update**

here is the [link](https://github.com/caffeinator13/srae) to my work with opennlp where I have created models and used them. The code self-explanatory. get back to me if you have any doubts.

Comment: I have tried all options such as putting the training data in text file and creating model out of it. Even tried giving 15000 sentences. None of the options worked. Main issue while testing the model, the output comes as blank although there was no error creating the model file. Could you kindly share a working sample consisting of the test class(to test the model) along with the code that generates the model. Thanks

Comment: find the link to my repository in the update to my answer. get back to me in case of any doubts.